# Application error TermServLicensing

Tags: windows

Since a couple of weeks we get this error in our application log:

```
Faulting application name: svchost.exe_TermServLicensing, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bc3c1
Faulting module name: tls236.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7c9d9
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000002c5d
Faulting process id: 0x7b8
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf87bdab8c4711
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\tls236.dll
Report Id: 8b454229-f471-11e3-858c-005056976264
```

I can't find the error somewhere else on the internet. Does anyone have a solution for this? Its specific about the faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\tls236.dll

Server is running Windows server 2008 R2 64-Bit.
We have 4 Terminal Servers (windows server 2008 R2 64-bit) who make connection with this server for the CAL's.

I don't know what further information is needed but if its needed please let me know and i'll post it.

***Edit***
there is no way i can reproduce this error. Sometimes i see it twice a day and some times i see it once each 2 days. So when some has a solution it will take time to notice if its solved or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lot of good information that may help you. Particularly the last post in the thread.

[svchost.exe_TermService crashes after installation of KB2621440](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f5855b60-f29c-4c90-b364-e364589e5267/svchostexetermservice-crashes-after-installation-of-kb2621440)